# Fallo con foreign key constreint en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Hola buenas tengo la siguiente base de datos

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS BuscoPareja;
CREATE DATABASE BuscoPareja;
USE BuscoPareja;

/*CREAMOS TABLA USUARIOS*/
CREATE TABLE USUARIOS (
    email VARCHAR(50),
    passwd VARCHAR(20),
    nombre VARCHAR(20),
    foto MEDIUMBLOB,
    direccion VARCHAR(20),
    ciudad VARCHAR(20),
    pais VARCHAR(20),
    sexo ENUM('H', 'M'),
    PRIMARY KEY (email, passwd)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

/*CREAMOS TABLA PREFERENCIAS*/
CREATE TABLE PREFERENCIAS (
    email_user VARCHAR(50),
    passwd_user VARCHAR(20),
    tipo VARCHAR(20),
    ultima_vez DATE,
    misma_preferencia ENUM ('SI', 'NO'),
    PRIMARY KEY (email_user, passwd_user),
    CONSTRAINT fk_email_user FOREIGN KEY (email_user) REFERENCES USUARIOS (email)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_passwd_user FOREIGN KEY (passwd_user) REFERENCES USUARIOS (passwd)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;

/*CREAMOS TABLA CITAS*/
CREATE TABLE CITAS (
    email_citado VARCHAR(50),
    email_citante VARCHAR(50),
    exito ENUM('SI', 'NO'),
    fecha_hora DATETIME,
    ubicaciones VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (email_citado, email_citante),
    CONSTRAINT fk_email_citado FOREIGN KEY (email_citado) REFERENCES USUARIOS (email)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_email_citante FOREIGN KEY (email_citante) REFERENCES USUARIOS (email)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;

SHOW DATABASES;
SHOW CREATE TABLE USUARIOS;
SHOW CREATE TABLE PREFERENCIAS;
SHOW CREATE TABLE CITAS;
```

Y me da un error a la hora de crear la tabla `PREFERENCIAS` el cual es el siguiente:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 21 in file: '/home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/MartinSosa_Antonio_practica.sql': Can't create table `BuscoPareja`.`PREFERENCIAS` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,054 sec)
```

No se porque me da esta este error en teoria el codigo no tiene errores de sintaxis, si alguien sabe porque me da este error y como podria solucionarlo lo agradeceria muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: `fk_email_user` a qué fila única apunta. Dice que a `usuarios (email)`, pero si eso no es una fila única, porque la clave primaria es `email, passwd`, no puede identificar a cual pertenece. Lo mismo con `fk_passwd_user`. Yo diría, que la fk debería de ser contra la fila, conformada por las dos conlumnas. `    CONSTRAINT fk_email_user FOREIGN KEY (email_user) REFERENCES USUARIOS (email, passwd)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: Y lo mismo con la tabla citas. A que fila apunta cada foreign key.

Comment: Pero con la tabla citas no me da ese problema

Comment: Espera voy a comprobarlo asi a ver si me funciona

Comment: No asi es imposible que funcione

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás creando una PK compuesta, y apuntando las otras tablas a un único campo...
Se debe apuntar a la CLAVE, no a los campos individuales.

Por otro lado te sugiero NO usar una clave compuesta en usuarios, sino un único campo (email), ya que tu diseño permite que dos usuarios puedan utilizar el mismo e-Mail,, siempre que la clave sea levemente diferente (hasta por un único caracter). Analíticamente eso no está bien.